# Ajax does not work when I have function in form onsubmit

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, onsubmit

am using .NET 2 and ASP.NET AJAX 1.0. But Ajax does not work when I have a function in form `onsubmit`.

Just one textbox is in AJAX UpdatePanel and rest of the forms include submit button are out of UpdatePanel part.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="preSubmit();disableAllButton();">
```

These are the functions:

```
function preSubmit()
{
    var divWait = document.getElementById('divWait');
    divWait.style.display = "block";
}
function disableAllButton()  {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
        if ((inputs[i].type == 'button') || (inputs[i].type == 'submit')) 
            inputs[i].disabled = true;          
}
```

I check the validity of one textbox by ajax when lost focus and it worked fine but when I add those function above in form tag, ajax stops working.

Comment: what is your expectation and what is the behavior you are getting?

Comment: I check the validity of one textbox by ajax when lost focus. and it worked fine but when I add those function above in form tag, ajax stops working.

Comment: the question is onsubmit functions caused ajax 1.0 stops working??

Comment: I mean, the rest of the aspx: the updatepanels, the textboxes, etc.

Comment: well I found the solution:
I should put return true; at the end of two javascript functions.

Answer (score 3):

Return true after your javascript methods to allow the partial ajax postback:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="preSubmit();disableAllButton(); return true;">
```

Comment: if I add return false; then neither the ajax validation nor the form submit button dose not work.

Comment: well I found the solution:

I should put return true; at the end of two javascript functions. 

thanks dmck for the hint.